# Parse ksoap response

Tags: java, soap, ksoap

In response by

```
transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);
```

in debug mode in *responseDump* I have xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><GetListItemsResult><listitems xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
     xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
     xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
     xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<rs:data ItemCount="5">
   <z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='testtask1' ows_Status='Not Started' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_Predecessors='' ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows__Level='1' ows_Title='testtask1' ows_ID='1' ows_UniqueId='1;#{A6E41E02-46FD-4363-A4A3-440AF902B280}' ows_owshiddenversion='1' ows_FSObjType='1;#0' ows_Created_x0020_Date='1;#2012-02-28 09:55:49' ows_Created='2012-02-28 09:55:49' ows_FileLeafRef='1;#1_.000' ows_PermMask='0x7fffffffffffffff' ows_Modified='2012-02-28 09:55:49' ows_FileRef='1;#Lists/Tasks/1_.000' />
   <z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='testtask2' ows_Status='Not Started' ows_Priority='(1) High' ows_Predecessors='' ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows__Level='1' ows_Title='testtask2' ows_ID='2' ows_UniqueId='2;#{A320D923-8BC8-4341-B40A-4D39C1FB01DB}' ows_owshiddenversion='1' ows_FSObjType='2;#0' ows_Created_x0020_Date='2;#2012-02-28 09:55:58' ows_Created='2012-02-28 09:55:58' ows_FileLeafRef='2;#2_.000' ows_PermMask='0x7fffffffffffffff' ows_Modified='2012-02-28 09:55:58' ows_FileRef='2;#Lists/Tasks/2_.000' />
   <z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='testtask3' ows_Status='In Progress' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_Predecessors='' ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows__Level='1' ows_Title='testtask3' ows_ID='3' ows_UniqueId='3;#{84071EBA-F38D-4EA9-A912-F8DD0088BD38}' ows_owshiddenversion='1' ows_FSObjType='3;#0' ows_Created_x0020_Date='3;#2012-02-28 09:56:07' ows_Created='2012-02-28 09:56:07' ows_FileLeafRef='3;#3_.000' ows_PermMask='0x7fffffffffffffff' ows_Modified='2012-02-28 09:56:07' ows_FileRef='3;#Lists/Tasks/3_.000' />
   <z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='testtask4' ows_Status='Waiting on someone else' ows_Priority='(3) Low' ows_Predecessors='' ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows__Level='1' ows_Title='testtask4' ows_ID='4' ows_UniqueId='4;#{AD6ED317-3F07-4998-89D2-38D8B6F0756E}' ows_owshiddenversion='1' ows_FSObjType='4;#0' ows_Created_x0020_Date='4;#2012-02-28 09:56:16' ows_Created='2012-02-28 09:56:16' ows_FileLeafRef='4;#4_.000' ows_PermMask='0x7fffffffffffffff' ows_Modified='2012-02-28 09:56:16' ows_FileRef='4;#Lists/Tasks/4_.000' />
   <z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='testtask5' ows_Status='Not Started' ows_Priority='(2) Normal' ows_Predecessors='' ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows__Level='1' ows_Title='testtask5' ows_ID='5' ows_UniqueId='5;#{50BC423F-E6A5-4719-B734-E528A08AE83B}' ows_owshiddenversion='1' ows_FSObjType='5;#0' ows_Created_x0020_Date='5;#2012-02-28 19:22:52' ows_Created='2012-02-28 19:22:52' ows_FileLeafRef='5;#5_.000' ows_PermMask='0x7fffffffffffffff' ows_Modified='2012-02-28 19:22:52' ows_FileRef='5;#Lists/Tasks/5_.000' />
</rs:data>
</listitems></GetListItemsResult></GetListItemsResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

But method *envelope.getResponse()* return text below

```
anyType{listitems=anyType{data=anyType{row=anyType{}; row=anyType{}; row=anyType{}; row=anyType{}; row=anyType{}; }; }; }
```

**UPD1**
I read this [acticle](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data), but it's not solution for my response.

Ok, I'm trying parse the answer as below

```
 transport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope, headerList); // 1st step - call soap query
 SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
 SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
 String title= null;
    for (int i = 0; i < soapObject.getPropertyCount(); i++) { // soapObject.getPropertyCount()  is only one (!!!!)
        SoapObject resource = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i); // in resource only this - anyType{data=anyType{row=anyType{}; row=anyType{}; row=anyType{}; row=anyType{}; row=anyType{}; }; }
        title = resource.getAttribute("ows_Title").toString();
....
```

Comment: Can you also elaborate what the exact problem is you are having?

Comment: I can catch xml from *String  response = transport.responseDump;* but what should I do next step? Or How can I parse this string?

Comment: I meet the same question as you, have you fixed this problem now?

Comment: I am not remember solution, cause the project was close, but I think the problems in user' permissions or this method doesn't correct for it. Try to read msdn.com, I worked with sharepoint soap and its not easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried something like this:

```
SoapObject soapObject = envelope.getResponse();
for (int i = 0; i < soapObject.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
        SoapObject resource = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);
        String uri = resource.getAttribute("uri").toString();
        String mimeType = resource.getAttribute("mimeType").toString();
        String size = resource.getAttribute("size").toString();
        String localURI = resource.getAttribute("localURI").toString();
        //do stuff
}
```

note: this is an example I use to get properties from a list of resources

this example loops over the tags of the response SOAP object and gets the 3 known attributes of each tag, see example response below:

```
<resources xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
    <resource mimeType="text/xml" size="123456" uri="https://example.com/content/get.php?a123891" localURI="package.opf"/>
    <resource mimeType="application/x-dtbncx+xml" size="123456"  localURI="nav.ncx"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: I understood this idea, but I have bad data in *envelope.getResponse()* (like in the sample code in the question) and this does not  allows me parse correct data.

Comment: @Gorets you can parse as in my example, cast the response to 'SoapObject' and loop over the rows, and parse their values... the 'toString' might give you the impression that you 'getResponse' is empty, but that might might not be the case, the 'toString' is just returning an empty string maybe

Comment: 1st my query to auth wsdl service returned correct response, but next query with added auth data  in header is wrong